# How to draw hollow circle in Google Maps v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible do draw hollow circle in Google Maps v3?

More information: I need that my circle have a "hole" in it. Something like if you merge two circles with same center, one in another.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the options:

- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#CircleOptions

using `fillOpacity: 0.0` should do the job.

Comment: well, maybe i was not clear enough with my question... can you check updated part of my message.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, but you can simulate it by doing a polygon that looks like a circle. See this: view-source:http://www.geocodezip.com/dreacentral_com_NewMapOverB.html (zoom out to see a circle inside a rectangle.

Comment: i also tried to define width of the circle border. problem is that is defined in pixels, but i need it in meters...

Comment: Look at the source from the above link - it seems to be doing radius in miles.